# Multiple publishers for joint_state cause RViz to flicker

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have a car simulation in ROS `Melodic` with 4 wheels and a joint on top of it and I am getting behavior that I don't know how to solve even after searching that in the forum.

The wheels are actuated according to the following plugin

```
<!-- Add Skid Steer Plugin -->
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <robotNamespace>/my_car</robotNamespace>
            <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <covariance_x>0.0001</covariance_x>
            <covariance_y>0.0001</covariance_y>
            <covariance_yaw>0.0001</covariance_yaw>
            <leftFrontJoint>base_wheel_front_left</leftFrontJoint>
            <rightFrontJoint>base_wheel_front_right</rightFrontJoint>
            <leftRearJoint>base_wheel_rear_left</leftRearJoint>
            <rightRearJoint>base_wheel_rear_right</rightRearJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>2.11</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.71</wheelDiameter>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <torque>1000000</torque>
            <topicName>cmd_vel</topicName>
            <broadcastTF>false</broadcastTF>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
```

While the joints on top of the car are actuated using the transmission element like this one:

```
        <transmission name="chassi_boom_transmission">
            <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
            <joint name="base_mount_joint">
                <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            </joint>
            <actuator name="chassi_boom_actuator">
                <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
                <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
            </actuator>
        </transmission>
```

The problem is...  Whenever I spawn the joint_state_publisher, both gazebo and joint_state_publisher publish to the topic `joint_states`. However, the `gazebo` never updates its `joint_state` causing my simulation model to flicker.

```
$ rostopic info /my_car/joint_states 

Type: sensor_msgs/JointState

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://ps-imr:42743/)
 * /joint_state_publisher (http://ps-imr:38597/)

Subscribers: 
 * /robot_state_publisher (http://ps-imr:38075/)
```

I currently have one launch file to start the simulation and another one to start the ros_control layer.

part of My_car.launch:

```
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
        <remap from="/joint_states" to="/my_car/joint_states" />
    </node>
        <!-- Spawn the example robot -->
    <arg name="my_car_model" default="tesla" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find my_car_description)/urdf/tesla_my_car.urdf.xacro' my_car_model:=$(arg my_car_model)" />
    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param /robot_description -model my_car" />

    <!-- Publish TFs -->
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
        <remap from="/joint_states" to="/my_car/joint_states" />
    </node>
```

And that is part of my `control.launch`

```
<!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
<rosparam file="$(find belt_loader_control)/config/belt_loader_control.yaml" command="load" />

<!-- load the controllers -->
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/my_car" args="my_car_controller flex_ramp_controller joint_state_controller" />
```

Any thoughts about why that could be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374277/multiple-publishers-for-joint_state-cause-rviz-to-flicker/) by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-18**:\

> Whenever I spawn the joint_state_publisher,

why do you do this?

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-03-18**:
because otherwise I won't see the wheels in place in RViz. Even though I am still able to move it by publishing a message in `/cmd_vel`

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-03-18**:
I mean ... they are not event shown in my Robot Model. It states `No transform from [wheel_front_left] to [base_footprint]`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-18**:
The JSP will publish `JointState` messages for all `joint`s in your URDF. So starting the JSP in addition to Gazebo will cause conflicting messages to be published on `/joint_states`. That's probably the reason you see "flickering" (which is really just two different states being visualised in rapid succession by RViz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just realized I didn't add the transmission to the wheels

```
<transmission name="wheel_transmission_${position}">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="base_wheel_${position}">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wheel_actuator_${position}">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>
```

---

Originally posted by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) with karma: 68 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0